# Filter through JSON array of data using jQuery.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to set up a function that will filter through JSON array data being brought in from a different domain, but I am running into an error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

This is how things are setup so far:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://[website-name].org/json/North',
            context: this,
            dataType: "jsonp"
        }).done(function() {
            $.each(data, function(index) {
                alert(data[index].Name);
                alert(data[index].WaitTime);
            });
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

The url contains the JSON data setup in this exact format: `{"Name":"Facility Name","WaitTime":"30 min"}`

But it seems that the error is pointing to that exact setup. I'm not sure what I'm missing. I'm pretty new to using the jQuery.ajax function, so I may be missing something. The code never seems to make it to the .done part, and I think the JSON data is set up in the correct format (I could be wrong, though).

Comment: I believe you have to pass the `response/data` into the `done` method arguments. besides that I'm unsure why you're receiving that error.

Comment: you're missing your parameter in your done function, it needs to look like this `.done(function(data) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things wrong in your code. And they are,

```
.done(function(data) {
   var responseData = JSON.parse(data); //Convert the response string to actual JSON data
   $.each(responseData, function(index) {
      alert(responseData[index].Name);
      alert(responseData[index].WaitTime);

      //Please add a debug point using your devtools and see what is returned as index and act upon that data.
   });
});
```

In your code it should throw an error cus your are passing a string into the each function.

Comment: This got rid of the error message but the alerts do not appear to work. I don't see any indication that the data is being retrieved other than the lack of an error now...

Comment: I've made a change in the answer I've given, but it would be good for your to add a debug point to your code and see the execution.